# Инвентарь браузерной игры в двоичном массиве

Tags: алгоритм, php, разработка-игр

Есть динамический двумерный массив.
Есть база итемов.
Итем может занимать произвольное количество ячеек массива.

У итема есть параметр [координаты], где указаны координаты ячейки, где находится левый-верхний угол итема и дополнительно указаны его длинна и высота.
[Примерно вот такая схема имеется ввиду.](http://hotimg23.fotki.com/a/95_132/133_218/1328805174_scr828.jpg)

[image]

В данном случае: [crossbow:2-2:2:4].

Для переноса итема юзается drag-n-drop. НО, так как в базе инвентаря фактически итем находится в координатах одной клетки, то итемы элементарно накладываются один на другой.

А если итем приходит извне, то инвентарь вообще не генерируется: система проверяет записи координат, делает поправки x+width, y+height и вставляет итем в пустое место, если оно есть. Но такие проверки очень монструозны и затратны, так как все поправки должны упасть во временное хранилище занятых клеток и не учитываться при проверке на их свободность.

Можно подпереть костылём с другой стороны: при каждоё операции с инвентарём отсылать в базу новую версию маски занятых секторов в массиве, но тесты показали, что 4 человека усиленно переставляя итемы в инвентаре ложат нахрен всю базу и выедают непростительно много памяти.

Кто-то разрабатывал подобные системы? Решал подобные проблемы? Каким макаром такое можно оптимизировать? Или может я не замечаю какой нить более простой подход к теме?

Comment: А в чем монструозность и затратность проверок? Сложить две матрицы, при первой 2-ке выполнять какое-то действие.

  * при новом итеме искать свободное место
  * при пермещении итема просто не давать пихать туда где места нет - возвращать на прежнюю позицию

имхо, тетрис с квадратиками )

Comment: То есть первая матрица - текущий инвентарь, а вторая матрица - перетаскиваемый предмет? Но у них ведь разная размерность получается. 

И как поступить с ситуацией, когда нам нужно предмет 2х4 перенести на 1 ряд вправо? первая же проверка покажет, что в смежном ряду уже есть предмет (тот который переносится) и проверка зафейлится.

Comment: @lopar, когда вы подняли предмет - его нет в инвентаре ;) Далее, накладывать надо матрицу `текущий_инвентарь_без_предмета` + `пустой_инвентарь_с_предметом`, т.е. одной размерности. В самом банальном случае делаете матрицу из нулей и единиц и если при сложении есть хоть одна двойка - запрещаете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример из камента:

Есть (слева) инвентарь (занятые - 1, пустые - 0), 10х5

И есть (справа) предмет, допустим на данный момент в позиции [7;2], размером 2х3

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

При их сложении получится следующее:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 2 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Тут мы видим двойку - это значит, предметы накладываются и сюда поставить нельзя.

Накидал вам простенькую функцию подстановки предмета в матрицу. Вам остается только сложить массивы и проверить в сумме наличие двоек :)

Соответственно, при "добавлении в инвентарь" вам надо пробежаться по инвентарю и поискать в нем такие места, при добавлении предмета в которые этих самых двоек не возникает.

```
function getItemMatrix( $item /* x, y, w, h */ ) {
  $invWidth = 10;
  $invHeight = 5;
  $result = array();
  if ($item->x + $item->w > $invWidth or $item->y + $item->h > $invHeight)
    return false; // сюда ставить нельзя
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $invWidth; $i++) {
    $result[$i] = array();
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $invHeight ; $j++)
      $result[$i][$j] = ($i >= $item->x and $i <= $item->x + $item->w and $j >= $item->y and $j <= $item->y + $item->w ) ? 1 : 0;
  }
  return $result;
}

/*
- Аааа, я видел двойку!
- Успокойсся, Бендер, это был сон, двоек не бывает...
© futurama
*/
```

Comment: ну приводить к одной размерности матрицы не обязательно, достаточно пройти по матрице итема. матрицу базы смещаем на тестируемую позицию, плюс те же проверки на выход за границы. и считать можно в браузере все, на серваке просто доп проверки при апдейте, если надо... в общем как удобнее, в любом случае проверка довольно быстрая, вешать ничего не должно.